# Regretting a Mitzvah Anxiety

Tags: sources-mekorot, psych-mentalhealth

Are there sources for someone who constantly has anxiety about regretting his mitzvot? To better explain this, one who keeps doing mitzvot but has an anxiety that he regrets the mitzvot when he actually doesn’t?

Comment: I mean this with all due respect, and I don't know if you're talking about yourself or in general, but this sounds like a general OCD (more obsessive than compulsive) issue. Rav Asher Weiss in Minchas Asher has a teshuva about OCD, but that's more with respect to halacha (like was a person yotzi or not and they keep redoing the mitzvah just in case etc.). This seems less halacha related...

Comment: That sounds like [intrusive thoughts](https://theunitofcaring.tumblr.com/post/179326829326/scotts-post-the-chamber-of-guf-describes-one); they're unpleasant, but common and harmless.

Comment: I didn't get it, besides anxiety does he regret doing Mitzvas or not? And what part your "he actually doesn't" apply to?

Comment: See Tania chapter 31

Comment: @alberko I absolutely do not regret any mitzvot. Thoughts keep on coming in my head saying “I regret the mitzvot.” And these thoughts are making me extremely anxious, making me think that I’m gonna loose my reward for the mitzvot.

Comment: please give a full description of such a scenario: 1. you give Tzdoko 2. you don't regret 3. you have thoughts that you do regret... or what? I'd like to hear the full story. Also what do you mean by regret - please elaborate, like you say "what a foul I was doing that Mitzvah"? Or "a waste of money"? Give some real examples.

Comment: @alberko The thoughts don’t come particularly after I do a mitzvah. It just comes in general. There’s a thought in my head that says “I regret all my mitzvot” even though i certianley don’t. It’s almost as if the Satan is working overload. It’s hard to explain. Hashem is a righteous judge, so i know he knows that I truly don’t regret anything.